# python create a new column using multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-conditions

I'm just starting with Python and I have a big list of subjects and their (BMI) body mass index (along many more data).
I need to create a new column (called OMS) where I can state if they're "normal", "overweight", "obese", etcc.

but I just can't find the correct way to do it. I tried np.when but that only works with 2 conditions.

I tried the if, elif, else without success and also the:

```
df['oms'] = np.nan

df['oms'].loc[(df['IMC'] <=18.5 )] = "slim"

df['oms'].loc[(df['IMC'] >= 18.5) & (df['IMC'] <25 )] = "normal"

df['oms'].loc[(df['IMC'] >= 25) & (df['IMC'] <=30 )] = "overweight"

df['oms'].loc[(df['IMC'] > 30)] = "obese"
```

any ideas? I'm stuck.

Comment: Thanks guys!!! I'll work on it and let you know.

Comment: Just for the sake of fun and learn, I tried all 4 solutions you guys suggested and with the proper adjustments, all worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['IMC'].lt(18.5), 'oms'] = "slim"
df.loc[df['IMC'].ge(18.5) & df['IMC'].lt(25), 'oms'] = "normal"
df.loc[df['IMC'].ge(25) & df['IMC'].lt(30), 'oms'] = "overweight"
df.loc[df['IMC'].ge(30), 'oms'] = "obese"
```

You can also use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

```
bins = [0, 18.5, 25, 30, 9999]
labels = ['slim', 'normal', 'overweight', 'obese']

df = pd.DataFrame({'IMC': [15, 20, 27, 40]})
df['oms'] = pd.cut(df['IMC'], bins, labels=labels)
>>> df
   IMC         oms
0   15        slim
1   20      normal
2   27  overweight
3   40       obese
```

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe:

```py
df['oms'] = ""#keep it object dtype

df.loc[(df['IMC'] <=18.5 ), 'oms'] = "slim"
df.loc[(df['IMC'] >= 18.5) & (df['IMC'] <25 ), 'oms'] = "normal"
df.loc[(df['IMC'] >= 25) & (df['IMC'] <=30 ), 'oms'] = "overweight"
df.loc[(df['IMC'] > 30), 'oms'] = "obese"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda functions and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with panda dataframes.

I created a dummy data file:

```
bmi,height
20,72
22,73
26,77
5,66
13,60
```

imported the data file

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=0)
```

created a column like you did of NaNs (but you don't have to)

```
df["oms"] = np.nan
```

and then used a lambda to compare 'bmi' column to some criteria

```
df['oms'] = df['bmi'].apply(lambda x: 'slim' if x < 18.5 else ('normal' if x<25 else ('overweight' if x<30 else 'obese')))
```

the data looks like this,

```
print(df.head())

   bmi  height     oms
0   20      72  normal
1   22      73   obese
2   26      77   obese
3    5      66  skinny
4   13      60  skinny
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.select`, I like this alternative because it's very versatile and you can easily add or remove conditions.

```
import numpy as np

condlist = [df["IMC"] <= 18,
           (df["IMC"] >= 18.5) & (df['IMC'] <25),
           (df["IMC"] >= 25) & (df['IMC'] <=30),
            df["IMC"] > 30]

condchoice = ["slim", "normal", "overweight", "obese"]

df["oms"] = np.select(condlist, condchoice)
```